# Refer to univariate part of a multivariate polynomial

Tags: polynomials

I have a two variable polynomial $f(X,Y)$, for example $f=x^2-4+y$.

However I am only wanting to refer to the part of the polynomial in variable $x$, the bit $x^2-4$.
Is this done by the notation $f(X)$ or something else?

Bit of background. I have drawn a graph of the polynomial in $x$ and another of it in $y$. I am wanting to reference the one in $x$.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might use $f(x,0)$ which removes the $y$ part of the polynomial.